# I can't get my AMD APU to use the propriety drivers, is there anyway to fix this?

Tags: drivers

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP machine running on a AMD APU A4. For some reason I can't install the video drivers to play WoW. Can someone help me out and it keeps telling me to check my jlogs?

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- run `gksu jockey-gtk`. This will search for the drivers required for your AMD APU.

If the above doesn't work, open a terminal. Issue following,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```